# Como triggerear StepFunctions con S3

Tags: aws, lambda, template, amazon-s3

he intentado iniciar un `stepunction` con un archivo `S3` pero no detecta nada, quero que inicie cada vez que el objeto es creado

```
  AwsS3BucketNameTemp:
    Type: String
    Default: aws-s3-bucket-temp

  MyStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref AwsMyStateMachineName
      DefinitionUri: ./statemachine/state.asl.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        ProvisionedTempArn: !GetAtt S0ProvisionedTemp.Arn
      Policies:
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: "*"
      Events:
        Trigger:
          Type: EventBridgeRule
          Properties:
            EventBusName: default
            Input: 
            Pattern:
              source:
                - "aws.s3"
              detail-type:
                - "Object Created"
              detail:
                bucket:
                  name:
                    - !Ref AwsS3BucketNameTemp


  S3BucketTemp:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref AwsS3BucketNameTemp
      NotificationConfiguration:
        EventBridgeConfiguration:
          EventBridgeEnabled: True
```

El evento si se crea pero no hace nada, no inicia el `step functions`

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que te hayas saltado un paso. Tienes que activar el envío de notificaciones a Event Bridge desde S3.

Para hacer esto tienes que ir a las propiedades del bucket. Ahí localizas la sección "Event Notifications" y pulsas sobre el botón "Edit" en el apartado "Amazon EventBridge". Una vez allí activas "Send notifications to Amazon EventBridge for all events in this bucket".

No olvides guardar los cambios para que los mismos se apliquen.